# How to rearrange the viewholders in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have multiple view holders in recyclerview (5 view holders). I am getting data from API for first 4 viewholders and for 5th view holder I am giving static data. Now what I want is I want to place the static viewholder data into in postion 2.

For example:

> pos 0 = *data from API*,
> pos 1 = *data from API*,
> pos 2 = *Static data*,
> pos 3 = *data from API*,
> pos 4 = *data from API*.

So far what I have done is given below.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position < categoryAndVideoList.size() &&
            Constants.FEATURED_ARTIST.equalsIgnoreCase(categoryAndVideoList.get(position)
                    .getCategoryType())) {
        return TYPE_ARTIST;
    } else if (position == categoryAndVideoList.size()) {
        return TYPE_MOOD;
    } else {
        return TYPE_CATEGORY;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (categoryAndVideoList.size() == 1)
        return categoryAndVideoList.size();
    else
        return categoryAndVideoList.size() + 1;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int
        viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == TYPE_ARTIST) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_artist,
                parent, false);
        return new ArtistSongsHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_MOOD) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_mood,
                parent, false);
        return new MoodBannerHolder(view);
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout
                        .item_parent_home_sample,
                parent, false);
        return new RecentVideosHolder(view);
    }

}

    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder recentVideosHolder, final int
        position) {

    data = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!(recentVideosHolder instanceof MoodBannerHolder)) {
        data.addAll(categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getData());
    }
    /**
     * TYPE ARTIST
     */

    if (position < categoryAndVideoList.size() && Constants.FEATURED_ARTIST
            .equalsIgnoreCase(categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryType())) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.addAll(categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getData());
        artistAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(context, data, typeApiValues.get(position),
                position);
        ((ArtistSongsHolder) recentVideosHolder).artistRecylerView.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
        ((ArtistSongsHolder) recentVideosHolder).artistRecylerView.setOverScrollEnabled(true);
        ((ArtistSongsHolder) recentVideosHolder).artistRecylerView.setItemTransformer
                (new ScaleTransformer.Builder().setMinScale(0.7f).build());
        double deviceWidth = Utils.getDisplayWidthValue(context);

        deviceWidthCalc(deviceWidth, (ArtistSongsHolder) recentVideosHolder);

        //To get artist name - categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryName()
        ((ArtistSongsHolder) recentVideosHolder).header.setText
                (categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryName());

        ((ArtistSongsHolder) recentVideosHolder).tvSeeAll.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SeeAllActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("type", typeApiValues.get(position));
                        intent.putExtra("title",
                                categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryName());
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

    } else if (recentVideosHolder instanceof MoodBannerHolder) {
        moodAdapter = new MoodAdapter(context, moodBannerList, moodValue);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager childHomeLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(context,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodRecycler.setLayoutManager(childHomeLayout);
        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodRecycler.setAdapter(moodAdapter);
        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodHeader.setText(context.getString(R.string.home_mood_banner));

        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodRecycler
                .setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodRecycler.setFocusable(false);
        ((MoodBannerHolder) recentVideosHolder).moodRecycler.scrollTo(0, 0);

    }
    /**
     * TYPE CATEGORIES
     */
    else {
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            childRecyclerAdapter = new HomeVideosAdapter(context, data,
                    typeApiValues.get(position));

            /**
             * WEEKLY VIEW
             */
            if (typeApiValues.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WEEKLY)) {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).header.setText
                        (categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryName());

            }

            /**
             * TRENDING NOW VIEW
             */
            else if (typeApiValues.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TRENDING_NOW)) {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).header.setText(
                        context.getString(R.string.home_trending_now));

            }

            /**
             * TOP CHARTS VIEW
             */
            else if (typeApiValues.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TOP_CHARTS)) {
            }

            /**
             * TOP PICKS VIEW
             */
            else if (typeApiValues.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TOP_PICKS)) {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).header.setText(
                        context.getString(R.string.home_top_picks_for_you));

            } else if (position == 0) {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).header.setText
                        (categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryName());
            }

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager childHomeLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(context,
                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager
                    (childHomeLayout);
            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).childRecyclerView.setAdapter
                    (childRecyclerAdapter);
            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).childRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).childRecyclerView
                    .setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).childRecyclerView.setFocusable(false);
            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).childRecyclerView.scrollTo(0, 0);

            if (categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getLastPage() > 1) {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).seeAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).seeAll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (typeApiValues.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WEEKLY)) {
                ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).seeAll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).seeAll.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SeeAllActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("type", typeApiValues.get(position));
                            intent.putExtra("title",
                                    categoryAndVideoList.get(position).getCategoryName());
                            context.startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            ((RecentVideosHolder) recentVideosHolder).parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

My output is given below:

[image: home page]

What I want is I want *"how is your mood?"* list to be placed below the *"Trending Now"* list. I have searched a lot but I didn't find anything...
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the "static data" in the `categoryAndVideoList` at the desired position in the constructor or setter method for that list.

Then you can modify the `getItemViewType()` like below:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position < categoryAndVideoList.size() &&
            Constants.FEATURED_ARTIST.equalsIgnoreCase(categoryAndVideoList.get(position)
                    .getCategoryType())) {
        return TYPE_ARTIST;
    } else if (position ==YOUR_DESIRED_POSITION) {
        return TYPE_MOOD;
    } else {
        return TYPE_CATEGORY;
    }
}
```